# How to make a (sed) regex replacing all occurances of one character while deleting the last?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am struggling with the following. 
I am using commands like this in my Mac terminal to test my regex:

```
echo 'inputstring' | sed (-E) '/s///g'
```

I am trying to create a regex that:

- if and only if a word ends in the letter 'o', then:
- deletes this word-final 'o'
- replaces all occurrences of the letter 'i' to 'a' in this word

In this case, the inputstring is `filo fililo felo fale` and the expected output is `fal falal fel fale`

I can make a regex that does either the deletion or the replacement, but do not see how to combine them. If I put a semi column between them, I don't see how to put in the conditional part.

I am also having trouble defining 'the end of the word' position. I used `\b` but it doesn't seem to work (unlike `$` for end of string).

Comment: post the actual, testable input string

Comment: Good point, I just added this to the description. As well as the expected outcome.

Comment: sed won't be good for such case. Use `awk` instead

Comment: sed idea; replace words that end in 'o' with '#word#' with stripped 'o', replace all 'i' between two '#' with 'a', remove all '#' that appear immediately before/after a word (replace my example '#' with any suitable character).

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `sed` for this, but if this is an exercise to learn `sed`, do a loop like this:

```
sed -E 's/$/ /
  :a
  s/i([[:alnum:]]*o[^[:alnum:]])/a\1/
  ta
  s/([[:alnum:]]*)o([^[:alnum:]])/\1\2/
  ta
  s/ $//'
```

- In the first line I add a whitespace at the end, so we can treat the line end like any word end. The last line removes that whitespace later.
- The `s` command in line 3 searches for occurences of `i` in a word ending with `o` and replaces it with `a`. The `t` command loops back to mark `:a` to repeat this for all `i` in all `o`-ending words.
- Now the fifth line removes the ending `o` and another loop. Note that from a word ending with `oo`, both of them will get removed; it's unclear whether this is desired.

For references only, I use an `sed` version supporting the `o` option to the `s` command meaning only to preserve the matched part and throw away the rest. Also it knows the `\h` in the replacement to replace by the contents of the hold space. This makes the task a one-liner:

```
sed -E ':a;h;s/([[:alnum:]]*)o($|[^[:alnum:]])/\1\2/o;T;y/i/a/;x;s//\h/;ba'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Awk** would be more accurate and flexible for such case:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
       if ($i~/o$/) { sub(/o$/,"",$i); gsub("i","a",$i) } }1' <<<"filo fililo felo fale"
```

The output:

```
fal falal fel fale
```

---

Alternative ***Python*** command line approach:

```
python -c 'import sys,re; s = sys.stdin.read().strip(); 
print(re.sub(r"\b(\S+)o\b", lambda m: m.group(1).replace("i","a"), s))' <<<"filo fililo felo fale"
fal falal fel fale
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible to do with `sed` (I suspect that it probably isn't), but it's really easy to do with Python! Here's a script that does exactly what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""modify_strings.py"""

import sys
import re
import fileinput

# Iterate over lines of input
# (either read from files or from stdin)
for line in fileinput.input():

    # Split each line into tokens and preserve whitespace
    tokens = re.split(r'(\s+)', line)

    # Iterate over tokens
    for token in tokens:

        # If a word ends in 'o' then
        # perform the desired transformation
        if token.endswith('o'):
            token = token[:-1].replace('i', 'a')

        # Print out each token
        sys.stdout.write(token)
```

You can run it like so:

```bsh
echo 'filo fililo felo fale' | python modify_strings.py
```

And it produces the following output (as desired):

```
fal falal fel fale
```

If you really want `sed` to be involved, then you can probably get what you want by augmenting it with a little shell scripting. That might look something like the following `bash` script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# modify-strings.bash

for word in "$@"; do
    if grep -q 'o$' <<<"${word}"; then
        echo -n "${word} " | sed -e 's/i/a/g' -e 's/o$//';
    else
        echo -n "${word} ";
    fi;
done
echo
```

You would call this script like so:

```bsh
bash modify-strings.bash filo fililo felo fale
```

Comment: Everything is possible with `sed`, the question is whether it makes sense. In this case, I don't think so, see my answer for a solution.